# sp_xml_preparedocument won't parse value from tag with _x in name

Tags: sql-server, sqlxml

Strange thing with sp_xml_preparedocument. Why it not take value from **name_x** tag ?

```
declare @pXml nvarchar(max)
set @pXml = '<item>
<name_x>_x</name_x>
<name_1x>_1x</name_1x>
<name_y>_y</name_y>
</item>'

DECLARE @hDoc INT 
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @pXml  

SELECT name_x, name_1x, name_y
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, '/item', 2)
WITH
(
 name_x NVARCHAR(5),
 name_1x NVARCHAR(5),
 name_y NVARCHAR(5)
) xDoc
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know quite why it's not working (other than finding a few old threads that do suggest that the MSXML parser can struggle with underscores), but if you add a [`ColPattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186918.aspx), it's enough to force it to work:

```
declare @pXml nvarchar(max)
set @pXml = '<item>
<name_x>_x</name_x>
<name_1x>_1x</name_1x>
<name_y>_y</name_y>
</item>'

DECLARE @hDoc INT 
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @pXml  

SELECT * --name_x, name_1x, name_y
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, '/item', 2)
WITH
(
 name_x NVARCHAR(5) 'name_x', --<-- Explicit pattern
 name_1x NVARCHAR(5),
 name_y NVARCHAR(5)
) xDoc
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
```

Results:

```
name_x name_1x name_y
------ ------- ------
_x     _1x     _y
```

I would still recommend marc's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25013010/15498) unless or until you've got a demonstrable issue though

Comment: Thanks, ColPattern looks like exit :)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use the **native** XQuery support in SQL Server?

```
-- if you're dealing with XML - use the "XML" datatype!
declare @pXml XML = '<item>
                       <name_x>_x</name_x>
                       <name_1x>_1x</name_1x>
                       <name_y>_y</name_y>
                     </item>'


SELECT
    Name_x = @pXml.value('(item/name_x)[1]', 'nvarchar(5)'),
    Name_1x = @pXml.value('(item/name_1x)[1]', 'nvarchar(5)'),
    Name_y = @pXml.value('(item/name_y)[1]', 'nvarchar(5)')
```

This gives you an output of:

```
Name_x  Name_1x   Name_y
  _x      _1x       _y
```

Comment: -- if you're dealing with XML - use the "XML" datatype! This is no matter on issue described. And sp_xml_preparedocument looks like faster on big XML's ...

Comment: If change declare @pXml nvarchar(max) to XML it still not work with tags that have _x in name.

Comment: Using the **native XQuery** API, it works just fine - why can't you use that?

Comment: OpenXML performs better for large XML documents

Comment: @AlexA - so your optimizing for performance over correctness? Interesting.

Comment: No, i just want to know, is any known reason why it fails on such names. And OpenXML does not mentioned as obsolete and outdated as i know.